# rails 3 query string params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I try to make a simple message controller with new/create actions, when I call new action I give through query string the to_id param,

> /messages/new?to_id=1

that contains id of recipient, now my code is:

```
def new    
    @message = Message.new    
    @message.to = User.find(params[:to_id])
  end

  def create 
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    @message.from = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.save
        format.html { redirect_to messages_path }
      else 
        format.html { redirect_to common_error_path, :notice => "failed to send message" }
      end   
    end
  end
```

It's pretty default, my problem is that the changes in @message object that have been made in new action are not available in create action and I lose my to_id value, the first thing come to my mind is to store to_id value using session object, but I think it's not the best idea, maybe someone have better solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pass that parameter back with the `POST` on create.  For example, if you have a

`belongs_to :to, :class_name => 'User'`

association on your `Message` model, you could do

`app/views/messages/new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @message do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :to_id %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

The above assumes you've kept your `new` action the same. Now, on your `create` action, your `params[:message]` would be equal to `{:to_id => 1}` and would assign it properly.

Does that make sense?